# how to make columns out of sql results in python

Tags: python, oracle

I am trying to get a bunch of data in sql which has a result set like this:

```
      Name          Skillset     Point   
1   Student A        Jump         5      
2   Student A        Run          5      
3   Student A        Walk         5      
4   Student B        Jump         2     
5   Student B        Run          2       
6   Student B        Walk         2
```

I want to get the skill set and make them as column in python but I am not sure how to do it dynamically the expected output would be like this:

```
    Name           Jump    Run     Walk
1   Student A        5        5       5
4   Student B        2        2       2
```

I am quite not sure if this could be done in SQL but I wonder if this programmatically easier on doing it in python. Appreciate any advice, help, tips on this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Pandas is great for data transformations.

You can read data to a DataFrame with pandas.read_sql_query and then transform the DataFrame

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_sql_query('''select * from your_table''', sql_connection)
print(df.set_index(['Name', 'Skillset']).unstack())
```